# How do I dynamically move a listview up by X pixels?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to use LayoutParams like [set layout margins dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593095/set-layout-margins-dynamically), but AbsListView.LayoutParams does not have a setMargins() function.  I need to do this dynamically in the java, not using xml.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`AbsListView.LayoutParams` applies to the items in the list. You can cast to `MarginLayout.LayoutParams` for the list view itself, (depending on the ViewGroup it is in).

Comment: MarginLayout.LayoutParams does not have setMargins either

Comment: Correct, you just change the margin public fields like marginLeft and then call setLayoutParams